# Problems with Html.Action and OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I am experiencing an issue when using `Html.Action` in a view to display the result of an action which has CacheControl enabled on it.

**Code**

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*"]
public class CachedController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult CachedAction()
    {
        var model = GetFromDB();
        return PartialView(model);  
    }
}
```

---

In a SomeView.cshtml file, if I have the code

```
@Html.Action("CachedAction", "Cached")
```

I get an Http 500 error and the html for SomeView.cshtml gets sent to the browser enclosed within a *pre* tag like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            // HTML for someView.cshtml here
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows what the problem is here?

**NOTE:** 
The code works as expected if I remove the OutputCacheAttribute and I see the view rendered correctly.

Comment: instead of public viewresult write public partialviewresult

Comment: Tried that does'nt fix my problem. I am pretty sure that this is because of the caching thats done on the CachedAction.

Comment: Show us the stack trace from the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: @jgauffin. Thats another problem. I don't see a 500 stacktrace as I am able to see from other cases. This is what I see from chrome dev tools
http://imgur.com/DqDVV

Comment: I'm more interested in the "Preview" pane in dev tools. It doesn't matter that you don't get the error in the other case. For all I know it can have returned a cache hit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using attribute directly above action, not above controller definition.

Comment: [CacheControl(HttpCacheability.NoCache), HttpGet] set on action if you want not to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are setting the cache on the whole controller not the action.

Try moving it so that your code becomes this:

```
public class CachedController : Controller
{
     [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*"]
     public ViewResult CachedAction()
     {
          var model = GetFromDB();
          return PartialView(model);  
     }
}
```

Unless of course that was your intention, but its not clear from your question.

Comment: @Gatz, The current code requires that most actions on the controller need to be cached. Is there a way I can override the action to not be cached?

Answer (score 1):

I got a fix to my issue. I was using the OutputCache attribute to specify that the Output should not be cached for the actions in this controller, whereas only a few actions had this requirement, I was naively applying it to all actions on the controller.

I fixed the issue by removing the Cache from the controller, and decorating required action with the OutputCache attribute. There is also an issue with the way the ASP.NET MVC code renders a page if it has a Html.Action that is cached. I would expect the partial to not get loaded. But in this page, the entire page was not loaded.

I realize that this problem is largely contextual. I drew upon a lot of advice offered as comments and answers on this post. I also do not wish to mark my own answer as accepted. So if one of you guys consolidate some tips on debugging this issue and update your answers, Ill mark that as accepted.

Comment: "There is also an issue with the way the ASP.NET MVC code renders a page if it has a Html.Action that is cached. I would expect the partial to not get loaded. But in this page, the entire page was not loaded.". Did you manage to work around this? I just realized I was caching entire page instead of a portion(!) and showing incorrect user information.